# How to work expires time in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, cookies, time

I am new for angularjs. For my web application, i need to check expire time.

Assume expires time as 5 seconds, and stored these expires time into cookies, now after 5 seconds check my expires time and do whatever action need. Is it possible.

Please help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: expiration of what specifically?

Comment: Simply in my app i'm using user login functionality, after user login 5 seconds i need to logout user.

Comment: Provide code related to this process.

Comment: Of course it's possible and very easy. But depends on what you already have.

Comment: How it's possible @dfsq, i am not used any approach, this is new one

Comment: For example, you could setup a timer using setTimeout in run block or controller.

Answer (score 0):

you can use angular $timeout anywhere you want:

```
$timeout(function() {
        // whatever code you want to run after 3000 milliseconds
    }, 3000);
```

Make sure you declare $timeout in the list of your controller's dependencies. Also replace the comment line with the actual code that does what you want to happen after 3 seconds; in this case, logging the user out.